# Spring Roo Abstract child classes --testAutomatically fails

Tags: spring-roo

I am using a very simple domain model, created like this...

```
entity --class ~.domain.Contact --abstract --inheritanceType TABLE_PER_CLASS 
entity --class ~.domain.Student --extends ~.domain.Contact --testAutomatically 
entity --class ~.domain.Family --extends ~.domain.Contact --testAutomatically
```

then I am adding a few fields to each class...

```
field string --fieldName firstName --class ~.domain.Contact
field string --fieldName secondName --class ~.domain.Contact
field string --fieldName firstName2 --class ~.domain.Family
field string --fieldName secondName2 --class ~.domain.Family
```

Then my automatically generated tests fail. This looks like a bug to me, anbody see a way around this, or can I not use --testAutomatically on subclasses? (a bit rubbish!)

(I'm loosing faith at an early stage with Roo, grails is calling me back...)

Here is my stacktrace...

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building hostfamilyfinders
[INFO]    task-segment: [test]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [aspectj:compile {execution: default}]
[WARNING] advice defined in org.springframework.scheduling.aspectj.AbstractAsyncExecutionAspect has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]
[WARNING] advice defined in org.springframework.mock.staticmock.AnnotationDrivenStaticEntityMockingControl has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]
[WARNING] advice defined in org.springframework.mock.staticmock.AbstractMethodMockingControl has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO] [compiler:compile {execution: default-compile}]
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] [aspectj:test-compile {execution: default}]
[ERROR] Type mismatch: cannot convert from Contact to Student
[ERROR] Type mismatch: cannot convert from Contact to Student
[ERROR] Type mismatch: cannot convert from Contact to Student
[ERROR] Type mismatch: cannot convert from Contact to Student
[ERROR] Type mismatch: cannot convert from Contact to Student
[ERROR] Cannot instantiate the type Contact
[ERROR] The method findStudent(Long) is undefined for the type Contact
[ERROR] The method findStudent(Long) is undefined for the type Contact
[ERROR] The method findStudentEntries(int, int) is undefined for the type Contact
[ERROR] The method add(Student) in the type List<Student> is not applicable for the arguments (Contact)
[WARNING] advice defined in org.springframework.orm.jpa.aspectj.JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]
[WARNING] advice defined in org.springframework.mock.staticmock.AnnotationDrivenStaticEntityMockingControl has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]
[WARNING] advice defined in org.springframework.mock.staticmock.AbstractMethodMockingControl has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]
[WARNING] advice defined in org.springframework.mock.staticmock.AbstractMethodMockingControl has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]
[WARNING] advice defined in org.springframework.scheduling.aspectj.AbstractAsyncExecutionAspect has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Compiler errors : 
error at com.cicoders.com.hostfamilyfinders.domain.Student obj = dod.getRandomContact();
                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/charlieivie/Workspace/STS/hostfamilyfinders/src/test/java/com/cicoders/com/hostfamilyfinders/domain/StudentIntegrationTest_Roo_IntegrationTest.aj:34:0::0 Type mismatch: cannot convert from Contact to Student
error at com.cicoders.com.hostfamilyfinders.domain.Student obj = dod.getRandomContact();
                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/charlieivie/Workspace/STS/hostfamilyfinders/src/test/java/com/cicoders/com/hostfamilyfinders/domain/StudentIntegrationTest_Roo_IntegrationTest.aj:65:0::0 Type mismatch: cannot convert from Contact to Student
error at com.cicoders.com.hostfamilyfinders.domain.Student obj = dod.getRandomContact();
                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/charlieivie/Workspace/STS/hostfamilyfinders/src/test/java/com/cicoders/com/hostfamilyfinders/domain/StudentIntegrationTest_Roo_IntegrationTest.aj:79:0::0 Type mismatch: cannot convert from Contact to Student
error at com.cicoders.com.hostfamilyfinders.domain.Student obj = dod.getNewTransientContact(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/charlieivie/Workspace/STS/hostfamilyfinders/src/test/java/com/cicoders/com/hostfamilyfinders/domain/StudentIntegrationTest_Roo_IntegrationTest.aj:95:0::0 Type mismatch: cannot convert from Contact to Student
error at com.cicoders.com.hostfamilyfinders.domain.Student obj = dod.getRandomContact();
                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/charlieivie/Workspace/STS/hostfamilyfinders/src/test/java/com/cicoders/com/hostfamilyfinders/domain/StudentIntegrationTest_Roo_IntegrationTest.aj:105:0::0 Type mismatch: cannot convert from Contact to Student
error at com.cicoders.com.hostfamilyfinders.domain.Contact obj = new com.cicoders.com.hostfamilyfinders.domain.Contact();
                                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/charlieivie/Workspace/STS/hostfamilyfinders/src/test/java/com/cicoders/com/hostfamilyfinders/domain/StudentDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.aj:21:0::0 Cannot instantiate the type Contact
error at return Contact.findStudent(obj.getId());
               ^^
/Users/charlieivie/Workspace/STS/hostfamilyfinders/src/test/java/com/cicoders/com/hostfamilyfinders/domain/StudentDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.aj:42:0::0 The method findStudent(Long) is undefined for the type Contact
error at return Contact.findStudent(obj.getId());
               ^^
/Users/charlieivie/Workspace/STS/hostfamilyfinders/src/test/java/com/cicoders/com/hostfamilyfinders/domain/StudentDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.aj:48:0::0 The method findStudent(Long) is undefined for the type Contact
error at data = com.cicoders.com.hostfamilyfinders.domain.Contact.findStudentEntries(0, 10);
                                                         ^^^^^^^^^
/Users/charlieivie/Workspace/STS/hostfamilyfinders/src/test/java/com/cicoders/com/hostfamilyfinders/domain/StudentDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.aj:56:0::0 The method findStudentEntries(int, int) is undefined for the type Contact
error at data.add(obj);

/Users/charlieivie/Workspace/STS/hostfamilyfinders/src/test/java/com/cicoders/com/hostfamilyfinders/domain/StudentDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.aj:67:0::0 The method add(Student) in the type List<Student> is not applicable for the arguments (Contact)

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Mon May 02 17:06:08 BST 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 22M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 4):

please check https://jira.springsource.org/browse/ROO-316, example on the bottom.